# Loop timing out when adding new last rows with set value

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

One of my scripts being used for a fantasy hockey-like game is failing to execute as of last week after having worked without issue for the past 54 games of the NHL season. This was my first go at scripting, so there is likely a simple error here, but for the life of me I can't seem to sort out why this is timing out now whereas it was taking mere seconds to execute previously.

The script uses an edit trigger to pull the game number from a sheet called 'Scoring' and then adds a total of 20 rows to the end of the 'History' sheet with that game number value set in the first column, then copies the box score to those 20 rows, and finally a separate 'Scorecard' sheet uses the 'History' data to figure each participants score.

Suddenly, the script lags heavily when adding the new last rows and setting the first column value to the 'gamenum'. The script seems to lag at different rates, but now cannot seem to get past creating and setting the value of between 3 and 9 new last rows before timing out.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
M

```js
function statHistory(){
 var sourcesheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Scoring'); 
 var gamerange = sourcesheet.getRange('B1');
 var gamenum = gamerange.getValues();
 var statrange = sourcesheet.getRange('B11:W28');
 var stats = statrange.getValues();
 var teamgoalierange = sourcesheet.getRange ('B31:W32')
 var teamgoaliestats =teamgoalierange.getValues();

 var targetsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('History');

  for (var gamehist = 0; gamehist <=19;gamehist = gamehist + 1){
    targetsheet.getRange(targetsheet.getLastRow()+1,1).setValues(gamenum)
 }

 targetsheet.getRange(targetsheet.getLastRow()-19,2,18,22).setValues(stats)

 targetsheet.getRange(targetsheet.getLastRow()-1,2,2,22).setValues(teamgoaliestats)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
function statHistory() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const shs = ss.getSheetByName('Scoring');
  const gamerange = shs.getRange('B1');
  const gamenum = gamerange.getValue();
  const statrange = shs.getRange('B11:W28');
  const stats = statrange.getValues();
  const teamgoalierange = shs.getRange('B31:W32')
  const tgstats = teamgoalierange.getValues();
  const tsh = ss.getSheetByName('History');
  let a = []
  for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++{ a.push([gamenum]) }
  tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1,a.length,a[0].length).setValues(a);
  tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() - 19, 2, stat.length, stats[0].length).setValues(stats);
  tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() - 1, 2, tgstats.length, tgstats[0].length).setValues(tgstats);
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this approach @Cooper—I am getting the following Syntax error: `Unexpected token '{' line: 12 file: Stat History 2.0.gs` regarding the `{` after `i++`.

Comment: Sat with this for a moment and realized there was a `)` missing after `i++` which resolved the syntax error. However, this approach still leads to the same issue of the script timing out when attempting to create the new last rows and push the gamenum value. Strange. Any other ideas by chance? Thank you!

Comment: Well I guess you still have some debugging to do.

Comment: :) had caught the missing `s` in `stats.length` and was experiencing the same timeout issue @ 6mins of execution. BUT, oddly enough, everything is back to working normally now. Both my original code and your code work perfectly—yours being a bit faster and concise. I am left scratching my head still as with nothing changed the original code went from working->not working->working over the course of a couple days, and your code went from not working->working in about an hour. Reasonable to assume this was something outside of my control and perhaps related to my use of IMPORTHTML or IMPORTXML?

Comment: @Lookwright See [IMPORTXML function was working for two months then stopped this morning](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/153166088/importxml-function-was-working-for-two-months-then-stopped-this-morning?hl=en)

Comment: Thank you @Rubén. Saw some of these posts which is what had led me to the conclusion that perhaps because the data involved in the script was derived from a combo of `IMPORTHTML` & `IMPORTXML`, that is was experiencing issues.